# How to print out information from data used in arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

My code asks for a user to enter how many wins, losses, and ties 6 different sports teams have gotten throughout a season. How can I make it so that once all the information has been received, it will print out how many wins, ties, and losses each team have gotten, as well as displaying the total amount of each?

Code:

```
package SMKTeamStandings;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SMKTeamStandings {

public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int number(int max, int min) {
    int teamchoice = 0;
    for (boolean valid = false; valid == false;) {
        teamchoice = in.nextInt();
        if (teamchoice >= min && teamchoice <= max) {
            valid = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a different value.");
        }
    }
    return teamchoice;
}

public static boolean finished(boolean[] completedArray) {
    int i = 0;
    boolean done;
    for (done = true; done == true;) {
        if (completedArray[i++] == false) {
            done = false;
        }
    }
    return done;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int teamChoice = 0, gamesNum;

    String[] sportteams = {"Basketball", "Football",
       "Hockey", "Rugby",
       "Soccer", "Volleyball"};


    boolean[] completed = new boolean[sportteams.length];
    int[][] Outcome = new int[64][sportteams.length];

    for (boolean done = false; done == false;) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sportteams.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + 1 + " - " + sportteams[i]);
            if (completed[i] == true) {
                System.out.println(" - Finished");
            } else {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        System.out.print("\nChoose a team from the list above:");

        teamChoice = number(6, 1);
        teamChoice--;

        System.out.print("\nHow many games total did the " + sportteams[teamChoice]
                + " team play this season?: ");

        gamesNum = in.nextInt();

        System.out.format("\n %10s %10s %10s %10s %10s \n\n", "", "Possible Outcomes:",
                "1 - Win",
                "2 - Tie",
                "3 - Loss");

        for (int wintieloss = 0; wintieloss < gamesNum; wintieloss++) {
            System.out.print("\nEnter the outcome for game "
                    + (wintieloss + 1) + ": ");
            Outcome[wintieloss][teamChoice] = number(3, 1);
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        completed[teamChoice] = true;
        done = finished(completed);
```

Comment: I'm very new to Java in general, so please go easy on me and try not to roast me too much haha.

Comment: I'm really tired right now to check the code, but you can replace "valid == false;" in your for loop with just "!valid".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to output the data you got from the user. To do that you could go through the data array using a for loop and accessing the data using indices.

```
for(int team = 0; team < sportteams.length; team++) { // for each team
    System.out.println((team + 1) + " - " + sportteams[team]); // output the team
    int game = 0; // index of the current game
    while(Outcome[game][team] != 0) { // while there is data
        System.out.print("Game " + (game + 1) ": " + Outcome[game][team] + " "); // print the data
        game++; // increment the index
    }
    System.out.println("Total games: " + game); // print the last index == total number of games
    System.out.println();
}
```